# How can I resize a partition on OSX 10.10.5

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

I have a Mac with OS X 10.10.5 on a HD which had 4 partitions.

Using Disk Utility I deleted one of the 4, intending to slightly grow the 3rd (containing the OS), leaving space for a new partition to install El Capitan.

This has been my practice up to now when a new version comes out.

I booted to another HD and deleted the partition, but it then proceeded to resize the 3rd partition YoodenVranx to use all the free space.

There seems to be no way to change the Partition Layout, or resize the partition.

I rebooted and used diskutil to list the current state.

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Fenchurch               80.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS BxxxxxData              70.0 GB    disk0s3
   4:          Apple_CoreStorage                         349.0 GB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS YoodenVranx            *348.6 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s4
```

Answer (score 3):

To get some additional un-allocated disk space on disk0 to create a new partition you have to shrink your CoreStorage Volume Group and all subsequent CoreStorage items.

To resize the CoreStorage Volume Group in your case you have to use the Terminal booted to an external boot drive.

**Preparation:**

- Backup your data.
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive) except your external boot drive.
- Boot from your external drive or a bootable installer thumb drive (Mavericks or Yosemite)/a thumb drive containing a full system (Mavericks or Yosemite).

  or

  Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot to a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

**Modify CoreStorage stack:**

- Open Disk Utility and check your disks for errors. Repair them and quit Disk Utility.
- Open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal

First you should get an overview of your disks and the partition layout:

- Enter `diskutil list`:

  Example listing:

  ```
  /dev/disk0
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
     1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS Fenchurch               80.0 GB    disk0s2
     3:                  Apple_HFS BxxxxxData              70.0 GB    disk0s3
     4:          Apple_CoreStorage                         349.0 GB   disk0s4
     5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5
  /dev/disk1
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *100.1 GB   disk1
     1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS BlinkenDonx              99.9 GB    disk1s2
  /dev/disk2
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:                  Apple_HFS YoodenVranx            *348.6 GB   disk2
                           Logical Volume on disk0s4
  ```

  with disk0: your internal disk, disk1: a fictional external boot drive with 100 GB containing your boot volume (BlinkenDonx) and disk2: your CoreStorage Volume Group YoodenVranx residing in disk0s4.
- Enter `diskutil cs list`

  Example listing:

  ```
    CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
  |
  +-- Logical Volume Group A629E051-D7B0-4B8C-A803-074F62704636
      =========================================================
      Name:         YoodenVranx
      Status:       Online
      Size:         349046696192 B (349.0 GB)
      Free Space:   16777216 B (16.8 MB)
      |
      +-< Physical Volume 90C09FC0-4215-4871-901B-70E2C9C7D464
      |   ----------------------------------------------------
      |   Index:    0
      |   Disk:     disk0s2
      |   Status:   Online
      |   Size:     349046696192 B (349.0 GB)
      |
      +-> Logical Volume Family F6962E38-50E4-4458-BFE6-CF2E179352F5
          ----------------------------------------------------------
          Encryption Status:       Unlocked
          Encryption Type:         None
          Conversion Status:       NoConversion
          Conversion Direction:    -none-
          Has Encrypted Extents:   No
          Fully Secure:            No
          Passphrase Required:     No
          |
          +-> Logical Volume BD36C73D-860D-4DC6-B125-AD624F448B88
              ---------------------------------------------------
              Disk:                  disk2
              Status:                Online
              Size (Total):          348696696192 B (348.6 GB)
              Conversion Progress:   -none-
              Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
              LV Name:               YoodenVranx
              Volume Name:           YoodenVranx
              Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
  ```
- Now resize the CoreStorage volume with

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack LVUUID size
  ```

  with LVUUID: UUID of the logical volume and size: the final size of your CoreStorage volume.
  Examples:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack BD36C73D-860D-4DC6-B125-AD624F448B88 300g
  ```

  to shrink it to 300 GB

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack BD36C73D-860D-4DC6-B125-AD624F448B88 295400m
  ```

  to shrink it to 295.4 GB

  Your Recovery HD should be moved automatically.
- To add an additional partition for your future El Capitan volume enter first:

  ```
  sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
  ```

  to get an overview

  Example listing:

  ```
  gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=500119476736; sectorsize=512; blocks=976757816
  gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
  gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
  gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 976757815
        start       size  index  contents
            0          1         PMBR
            1          1         Pri GPT header
            2         32         Pri GPT table
           34          6         
           40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640  156250000      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    156659640  136718750      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    293378390  544921872      4  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    838300262    1269536      5  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    839569798  137187985         
    976757783         32         Sec GPT table
    976757815          1         Sec GPT header
  ```

  with i=1: EFI 2: Fenchurch 3: BxxxxxData 4: Apple_CoreStorage 5: Recovery HD and about 70.2 GB free space (assuming you shrunk your CoreSorage volume to ~279 GB in the previous step to be able to create a new 70 GB volume).
- To create a new volume with `gpt` you have to unmount all mounted volumes on disk0 (first the CoreStorage volume, which has its own disk identifier disk2 but resides on disk0, then all other mounted volumes on disk0)

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```
- Now add a new JHFS+ volume with gpt:

  ```
  sudo gpt add -b StartBlock -i IndexNumber -s SizeOfVolume -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  ```

  StartBlock is the number of the first block in the unallocated space and NumberOfBlocks is the number of free blocks or smaller. NumberOfBlocks has to be dividable through 8!

  For the example above that's:

  ```
  sudo gpt add -b 839569798 -i 6 -s 137187984 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  ```
- Enter `exit` and quit Terminal.
- Open Disk Utility and erase your newly created partition disk0s6 (Journaled HFS+) and rename it.
- Then check your shrunk CoreStorage volume for errors.
- Quit Disk Utility.
- Reboot to your main volume.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I cannot accept it, as I did not actually implement this (although I am sure it would work). See my answer below. I will bookmark this for future use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which let me resolve my issue. I was sure this was related to Apple `CoreStorage`.
I could not find much about managing `CoreStorage`, but found a number of posts which explained how to convert these to HFS+, which is as simple as executing the following command.

```
diskutil coreStorage revert Logical Volume UUID
```

See http://awesometoast.com/yosemite-core-storage-and-partition-woes/ for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements there is a second method to quickly resize and add a second volume: resize the CoreStorage Volume (instead of the whole group) and add a second CoreStorage Volume inside the existing CoreStorage Volume Group. This procedure doesn't change the partition map (in contrast with the procedure in [my other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209176/93229) here).

**Preparation:**

- Backup your data.
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive) except your external boot drive.
- Boot from your external drive or a bootable installer thumb drive (Mavericks or Yosemite)/a thumb drive containing a full system (Mavericks or Yosemite).

  or

  Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot to a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

**Modify CoreStorage stack:**

- Open Disk Utility and check your disks for errors. Repair them and quit Disk Utility.
- Open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal
  First you should get an overview of your disks and the partition layout:
- Enter `diskutil list`:

  Example listing:

  ```
  /dev/disk0
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
     1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS Fenchurch               80.0 GB    disk0s2
     3:                  Apple_HFS BxxxxxData              70.0 GB    disk0s3
     4:          Apple_CoreStorage                         349.0 GB   disk0s4
     5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5
  /dev/disk1
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *100.1 GB   disk1
     1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS BlinkenDonx              99.9 GB    disk1s2
  /dev/disk2
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:                  Apple_HFS YoodenVranx            *348.6 GB   disk2
                           Logical Volume on disk0s4
  ```

  with disk0: your internal disk, disk1: a fictional external boot drive with 100 GB containing your boot volume (BlinkenDonx) and disk2: your CoreStorage Volume Group YoodenVranx residing in disk0s4.
- Enter `diskutil cs list`

  Example listing:

  ```
    CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
  |
  +-- Logical Volume Group A629E051-D7B0-4B8C-A803-074F62704636
      =========================================================
      Name:         YoodenVranx
      Status:       Online
      Size:         349046696192 B (349.0 GB)
      Free Space:   16777216 B (16.8 MB)
      |
      +-< Physical Volume 90C09FC0-4215-4871-901B-70E2C9C7D464
      |   ----------------------------------------------------
      |   Index:    0
      |   Disk:     disk0s2
      |   Status:   Online
      |   Size:     349046696192 B (349.0 GB)
      |
      +-> Logical Volume Family F6962E38-50E4-4458-BFE6-CF2E179352F5
          ----------------------------------------------------------
          Encryption Status:       Unlocked
          Encryption Type:         None
          Conversion Status:       NoConversion
          Conversion Direction:    -none-
          Has Encrypted Extents:   No
          Fully Secure:            No
          Passphrase Required:     No
          |
          +-> Logical Volume BD36C73D-860D-4DC6-B125-AD624F448B88
              ---------------------------------------------------
              Disk:                  disk2
              Status:                Online
              Size (Total):          348696696192 B (348.6 GB)
              Conversion Progress:   -none-
              Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
              LV Name:               YoodenVranx
              Volume Name:           YoodenVranx
              Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
  ```
- Now shrink the existing CoreStorage Volume with:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeVolume LVUUID size
  ```

  with LVUUID: UUID of the existing Logical Volume. Example:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeVolume BD36C73D-860D-4DC6-B125-AD624F448B88 279500m
  ```
- Add a new Logical Volume in the existing CoreStorage Volume Group with:

  ```
  diskutil cs createVolume LVGUUID type name size
  ```

  with LVGUUID: UUID of the existing Logical Volume Group, type: file system, size: percentage or size.

  Examples:

  ```
  diskutil cs createVolume A629E051-D7B0-4B8C-A803-074F62704636 jhfs+ ElCapitan 100%
  ```

  All the available free space in the CoreStorage Volume Group will be allocated to the new Logical Volume.

  ```
  diskutil cs createVolume A629E051-D7B0-4B8C-A803-074F62704636 jhfs+ ElCapitan 50000m
  ```

  50,000 MB (50 GB) of the available free space in the CoreStorage Volume Group will be allocated to the new Logical Volume.
- Enter exit and quit Terminal.
- Open Disk Utility and check your shrunk and the new CoreStorage volume for errors.
- Quit Disk Utility.
- Reboot to your main volume.